# How to automatically make a Shebang line for the files made in vi?

Tags: vim

I tried some Vim functions like VimLeave and VimLeavePre to execute a script which adds the Shebang line automatically to all the files as soon as Vi is quitted.
But the problem occurs when we don't save the file and just quit.
The vi functionality should not be altered which means when we give vi filename it opens that file and when we close without writing, the file will not be created. In this case, the script should not be executed.
One more feature is, this script should be executed only for the first time of write.
Is it possible to write such a code?

Comment: Stuff being added to files by your text editor when you save/quit seems like an incredibly bad idea. At the very least, it would be wiser to have Vim add the line when the file is *loaded*, so that you can see it and remove it if it happens to be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading this **[Noah Frederick's](https://github.com/noahfrederick)** article [File Templates with UltiSnips and Projectionist](https://noahfrederick.com/log/vim-templates-with-ultisnips-and-projectionist). besides the article, he also has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsLTYEVJ6JU)

The great advantage of this method is that you get a dynamic Shebang instead of a static one, because most of us already have some sort of snippets plugin installed, and using static file skeletons wouldn't be in consonance with this solutions.

Note: The article is a little bit long but I guarantee you it worth reading.

For my personal use, I have adapted Noah's solution with something like this:

```
"             File: ultisnips_custom.vim - Custom UltiSnips settings
"       Maintainer: Sergio Araújo
" Oririnal Creator: Noah Frederick
"        Reference: https://noahfrederick.com/log/vim-templates-with-ultisnips-and-projectionist
"      Last Change: nov 20 2019 08:53
"      Place it at: after/plugin/ultisnips_custom.vim

" We need python or python3 to run ultisnips
if !has("python") && !has("python3")
  finish
endif

" This function is called by the autocommand at the end of the file
function! TestAndLoadSkel() abort
  let filename = expand('%')
  " Abort on non-empty buffer or extant file
  if !(line('$') == 1 && getline('$') == '') || filereadable('%')
    return
  endif

  " Load UltiSnips in case it was deferred via vim-plug
  if !exists('g:did_plugin_ultisnips') && exists(':PlugStatus')
    call plug#load('ultisnips')
    doautocmd FileType
  endif

  " the function feedkys simulates the insert key sequence in order to call
  " the template (skel)
   execute 'call feedkeys("i_skel\<C-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()\<CR>")'
endfunction

augroup ultisnips_custom
  autocmd!
  au Bufnewfile *.sh,*.zsh,*.html,*.css,*.py,*.tex,*.md,*.vim :call TestAndLoadSkel()
  "autocmd BufEnter *.sh,*.zsh,*.html,*.py execute 'call feedkeys("i_skel\<c-j>")'
augroup END

" vim: fdm=marker:sw=2:sts=2:et
```

Pay attention to the place where you have to put this file:
`after/plugin/ultisnips_custom.vim`

Note: For each filetype you want a Shebang you must create a snippet called `_skel` or you can adapt the code to fit your needs.

For my vim snippets I have this one:

```
snippet _skel "file header" w
"       file: ${1:`!p snip.rv = snip.fn`}
"     author: `!v g:snips_author`
"       site: `!v g:snips_site`
"    Created: `!v strftime("%b %d, %Y - %H:%M")`
"Last Change: `!v strftime("%b %d, %Y")`
${0}
endsnippet
```

On my vimrc I have some predefined variables that I can use on my snippets or _skel files:

```
let g:snips_author='Sergio Araujo'
let g:snips_site='https://dev.to/voyeg3r'
let g:snips_email='<voyeg3r ✉ gmail.com>'
let g:snips_github='https://github.com/voyeg3r'
let g:snips_twitter='@voyeg3r'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate buffer contents you should trap `BufWrite` instead. The script could then be executed many times, of course, but that's not a big deal, as we can easily guard against multiple buffer changes. For example,

```
augroup AddShebang | au!
    autocmd BufWrite * call s:add_shebang()
augroup end

let s:known_shebang = {
    \ 'awk': '/usr/bin/awk -f',
    \ 'perl': '/usr/bin/perl -w',
    \ 'python': '/usr/bin/env python',
\ }

function s:add_shebang()
    let l:cmd = get(s:known_shebang, &filetype)
    " filetype is known but shebang was not added yet
    if !empty(l:cmd) && getline(1) !~# '^#!'
        call append(0, '#!'..l:cmd)
    endif
endfunction
```